# How to correct unicode errors after converting file format?

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion, mobi, file-format

To convert `epub` to `mobi` I utilized on [online](https://www.epubconverter.com/epub-to-mobi-converter/) tool, but it seems to have resulted in [odd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36108790/262852) unicode errors.  Throughout the text there are `0092`, `0093` and `0094` in place of punctuation.

Is this likely to to be a problem with the source material?  Perhaps the author just used strange punctuation which results in hiccups and glitches during conversion?  Or, is this more likely a problem with the online converter?

I'll probably have to convert [manually](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=227861) with `Calibre`, which looks [doable](https://askubuntu.com/q/344339/45156).

Might this be a [problem](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/634/9853) with Amazon, or the Kindle e-ink reader itself?

*There are [some](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7719/9853) issues with sending `azw` or `azw3` to Kindle cloud via e-mail.*

Answer (score 4):

> To convert epub to mobi I utilized on online tool

Most online tools actually use Calibre as the conversion tool. I.e., you might as well use Calibre.

> Throughout the text there are 0092, 0093 and 0094 in place of punctuation.

There's most likely a problem with the original epub file. You might want to check your epub with the [IDPF validator](http://validator.idpf.org/) before converting it with Calibre.

If the validator doesn't report any problems, open the file with Calibre Editor and search and replace all numerical codes with the equivalent punctuation characters.

When using Calibre to convert your epub files make sure to select **AZW3** as the  target format. For even better results install [Kindle Previewer 3](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1003018611) and the [KFX plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=272407) and convert your epub files to KFX files.

Comment: For `azw3` I updated the question a bit.

Comment: You can't send azw3 files by mail. However, you can send KindleGen generated master mobi files (which contain azw3 and mobi versions) by mail.

Comment: I added a fix to the problem using calibre.

Answer (score 1):

> Originally Posted by mrh882 View Post I have an ebook that looks fine
>   in Calibre and the Kindle viewer. No weird characters. When I send it
>   to my K3, however, I get squares with question marks in them. These
>   are not replacing any characters - sometimes before a comma, after a
>   comma, or in the middle of a sentence.
>
> Hopefully someone knows why this is happening and what I can do to fix
>   it.
>
> Thanks for the help!! reconvert with the checkbox in 'look & feel'
>   that is labled 'transliterate unicode characters to ascii" checked.

https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=144247

The `transliterate` checkbox fixed my error, FWIW.  The publisher is [sterling](https://www.sterlingpublishing.com/), BTW, and, no I haven't, as of yet, checked that it's valid.

The Calibre note for that check box gives an example of going from Russian Cyrrilic to the English alphabet.  Perhaps it's an internationalization problem.